# Deutsches Wort für "second hand shop"

Tags: single-word-request

Bei "Second-Hand-Store/Laden" denke ich an Kleidung. Klar gibt es

> Gebrauchtwarenladen

aber das "Waren" lässt mich eher an Möbel oder Geschirr oder sowas denken.

- Gibt bzw. gab es so ein klassisches, zusammengesetztes Substantiv, das an Kleidung denken lässt?

Comment: Warum soll Second-Hand etwas mit Kleidung zu tun haben? Aus zweiter Hand kann alles sein.

Comment: Muss es zusammengesetzt sein?

Comment: Früher gab es Lumpensammler und (Ausbesserungs-/Flick-)Schneider; heute Ebay, Kleiderzirkel und Tauschpartys.

Comment: @äüö "Second-Hand" ist im Deutschen stark mit Mode assoziiert, weil es in den 1980er Jahren anfing in Mode zu sein, dass man demonstrativ bestimmte gebrauchte Kleidungsstücke in sein Outfit integriert. Second-Hand-Shop/Laden ist in der Folge eine übliche Bezeichnung für Gebrauchtbekleidungsläden, auch wenn der modische Duktus heute nur noch ein Stil/Trend unter vielen ist ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ich fürchte, den gesuchten Äquivalentbegriff gibt es nicht. Trotzdem hier mal eine Zusammenfassung:

Wir sagen häufig "Second-Hand-Klamotten" oder "Second-Hand-Kleidung", die es im "Second-Hand-Laden" oder "Second-Hand-Shop" zu kaufen gibt.

Der Begriff wurde also ins Deutsche übernommen.

Begriffe wie "Gebrauchtkleidung" oder "gebrauchte Kleidung" gibt es natürlich auch, wird aber eher selten verwendet, da sich "Second Hand" besser (trendiger) anhört. "Altkleider" benutzt man meist im Zusammenhang mit den Einsammeln gebrauchter Kleidung für meist wohltätige Zwecke, wobei diese Ware dann aber wiederum im "Second-Hand-Laden" verkauft wird.

Ausdrücke wie "zweite Hand" wird meist nur bei gebrauchten Fahrzeugen verwendet. Bisweilen aber auch als Zusatz, wie z.B. "Second-Hand-Kleidung - Mode aus zweiter Hand".

Eine "Kleiderkammer" ist meist dazu da, Bedürftige mit Kleidung zu versorgen.

Etwas sperrig klingt heute: "Gebrauchtwarenhändler", "Trödler" oder "An- und Verkauf" und deutet auch nicht speziell auf Kleidung hin.

"Second-Hand" kann sich im Prinzip auf alle Gebrauchtwaren beziehen. Der Begriff "Second-Hand-Laden" (ohne weiteren Zusammenhang) wird aber i.d.R. mit Kleidung assoziiert. Bei Büchern gibt es den Begriff "Antiquariat".

Comment: In der DDR, wo sich der Einfluss der englischen Sprache in Grenzen hielt, hieß das `An- und Verkauf`. Z.B. "im An- und Verkauf einkaufen".

Comment: Ganz früher hieß das glaube ich `Kommissionsladen`.

Comment: In Berlin gab es schon vor eBay und "Second-Hand" eine Zeitung namens "Zweite-Hand" in der man diverse Gebrauchtwaren anbieten und kaufen konnte, von Kleidung bis zu Autos.Also war die deutsche Übersetzung von Second-Hand durchaus auch üblich.

Comment: Kleine Notiz: Der Begriff wurde nicht nur ins Deutsche übernommen, sondern sogar vom Duden aufgenommen: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Secondhandshop

Comment: An- und Verkauf!!! Das ist gut. Da gab es zumindest da wo ich aufgewachsen bin ein paar von, und die hatten vor allem Kleidung.

Answer (score 1):

Ein in den vorherigen Antworten und Kommentaren noch nicht aufgeführter Begriff existiert für gebrauchte Printmedien: *modernes Antiquariat*

Dort bekommt man Bücher und Zeitschriften, die wenige Monate oder Jahre alt sind (im Unterschied zum Antiquariat, das man üblicherweise mit Büchern assoziiert, die etliche Jahrzehnte alt sind).